# Jacobian matrix for $x^2+yz+z^2$?

Tags: matrices, analysis

let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x,y,z) = x^2 +yz +z^2$ (this was given)

1.) I had to show that f is differentiable in $\mathbb R^3.$
I showed this by doing partial differentation $(f_x = 2x, f_y = z, f_z = 2z+y)$.

2.) I need the jacobian matrix
Here I noticed that for $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ I should have a $2 \times 3$-matrix. However, the definition of f above seems to belong to $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ ?!

Comment: With $f$ as you've defined it, $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so its jacobian is a 1x3 matrix (its gradient). So yes, there is a mistake somewhere, the most likely alternative the $\mathbb{R}^2$ should be $\mathbb{R}$.
As a remark, you need to state that the partial derivatives are continuous to deduce that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: If I state that the partial derivatives are continuous, have I shown then that f is differentiable or that f is continuous-differentiable?

Comment: You've shown that it is continuously differentiable, but in particular it is differentiable. What I'm trying to emphasize is that if you wanted to show differentiability by definition you would have to compute an ugly limit, and while showing that the partial derivatives are continuous is "overkill" for your particular problem, it is still easier.